# How do I fix this attribute error in my Django App?

Tags: python, django, middleware

I am developing a Django app and I've created a place where the users can upvote or downvote a film, the problem is that when I hit one of these buttons this error shows up:

```
in likesDislikesPelicula
voto = Likes.objects.filter(usuario=request.Usuarioclte, pelicula__pk=idpelicula)

AttributeError: 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'Usuarioclte'
```

my views.py

```
def detallesPelicula(request, pelicula_id):
    peliculas = get_list_or_404(Pelicula.objects.order_by('titulo'))
    pelicula = get_object_or_404(Pelicula, pk=pelicula_id)
    actor = get_list_or_404(Actor.objects)
    likes = conteolikes(pelicula)
    dislikes = conteodislikes(pelicula)
    context = {
        'pelicula': pelicula,
        'peliculas': peliculas,
        'likes': likes,
        'dislikes': dislikes
    }
    return render(request, 'detallesPelicula.html', context)

def conteolikes(pelicula):
        return pelicula.users_vote.filter(valor__gt=0).count()

def conteodislikes(pelicula):
        return pelicula.users_vote.filter(valor__lt=0).count()

@csrf_exempt
def likesDislikesPelicula(request):
      if request.method == 'POST':
          idpelicula= request.POST.get('idpelicula','')
          valor = request.POST.get('valor','')
          try:
             voto = Likes.objects.filter(usuario=request.Usuarioclte, pelicula__pk=idpelicula)
             print("Existe")
             print(voto)
          except  Likes.DoesNotExist:
             print("No existe")
```

my models.py (Simplified)

```
class Usuarioclte(models.Model):
    nickname = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    contraseña = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nickname

class Likes(models.Model):
    #necesito que usuario y pelicula sean una calve compuesta
    #usuario_id= models.ForeignKey(User.id,on_delete= models.CASCADE)
    pelicula =  models.ForeignKey(Pelicula, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name = 'users_vote')
    usuarioclte = models.ForeignKey(Usuarioclte, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name= 
    'likes_and_dislikes')

    valor = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.usuarioclte.nickname
```

Note: The users are taken and stored by the Django Authentication system, not in a table that I've created.

I have seen that is has to do something with the `MIDDLEWARE` and `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES`, I've tried to change it but still doesn't work

my MIDDLEWARE in `setting.py`

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware', #i18n
'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
```

Comment: If you properly set ```User``` model in your settings file (e.g. ```AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'users.Usuarioclte'```) then you need just call ```request.user``` instead of ```request.Usuarioclte``` and it will be your ```Usuarioclte``` model object.

Comment: If I add AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'users.Usuarioclte' and change to request.user this error appears:                                      
                                                                                        "AUTH_USER_MODEL refers to model '%s' that has not been installed" % settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: AUTH_USER_MODEL refers to model 'users.Usuarioclte' that has not been installed

Comment: In which app your model ```Usuarioclte``` is declared? Use it's name instead of ```users``` in ```'users.Usuarioclte'```.